# MANIFEST. Does the Class-path in the MF file support wildcards?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I have a question,who can talk with me? In the Manifest.MF file. Which moudle execute the Class-path? Is it JVM? And can the Class-path support wildcards?

such as the "*" symbol, i tried, but it didn't work! Thanks ,my English is not well.

Comment: see the [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute) || The class loader uses the CLASSPATH to find the classes/resources - the specification does NOT mention anything about `*`, which confirms your results (it does not work)